# Apache rewrite to new page with parameters included

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters

I have external sites linking to my page at:

http://www.example.com/old.php?page=55555

but now I need them redirected to:

http://www.example.com/new.php?page=55555

A have seen redirects solved, but those were different, they were translated to a different kind of url (eg. example.com/page/55555) or other domain, not the same domain and same url construction.

I did get it to work without the parameters using 
RewriteRule old.php new.php, but this does not work when passing the params.

Just renaming the page is not an option :)
Thanks !

EDIT:

This is the code that works, but only without the parameters. Whenever you add "?page=55555", it does not work anymore.

```
RewriteRule old.php new.php [R=302,NC]
```

This is another variation I had tried, but could not get it to work:

```
RewriteRule ^old\.php?([0-9]*) new.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

EDIT2:

The answer given works, however it does only when I remove the following 4 lines from the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !marker  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?new.php$ %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?p([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ new.php?marker&page=$1 [L]
```

These 4 lines make it possible to enter 
http://www.example.com/p4444 
in the browser, and it will open 
http://www.example.com/new.php?page=4444 
(but still mask it with http://www.example.com/p4444)

I would like both old.php and new.php to work this way. I hope this is clear.

Comment: can you update your question to include your .htaccess?

Comment: thanks Ben, I added 2 lines of different code I have tried.

Comment: did you put the `RewriteRule old.php new.php [R,NC,QSA,L]` just before the `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !marker`?

Comment: yes before, I also tried it after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`[QSA]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) should be used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule old.php new.php [R,NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: I could not get it to work. I get a 404 error (I think because old.php does not exist ?).
I also tried other variations, with the QSA, those did not work either.

Comment: just made some update, should enable `RewriteEngine`

Comment: also you need to set `AllowOverride All` in config file

Comment: Your answer is correct and also works.
However, there is a conflict with an existing part in the .htaccess,
should I also post that here since it it related, of do I have to open up a different question for it ?